# error in mysql user password

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, passwords, phpmyadmin

I am using `Ubuntu 10.10` and I installed `phpmyadmin` from synaptic package manager.

But i did not put any password on mysql root user and phpmyadmin user.

Later, i tried to log into phpmyadmin with user `root` and no password it get error

```
Login without a password is forbidden
by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)
```

And chage password in mysql is not working, I tried to update password using `password('pma')` in passsword field in `user` table of `mysql` database, but still I am not being able to log in from console.

How to change mysql password, and where is this phpmyadmin configuration file.

Comment: Try running a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` inside MySql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the larger problem, but phpMyAdmin's configuration file is stored in `phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`. The username and password can be found on line 85:

```
85  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'root';      // MySQL user
86  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'root';      // MySQL password (only needed
87                                                      // with 'config' auth_type)
```

Comment: thanks that was helpful, but creating a user with all privilege solved my  problem. If you update your answer, i will accept it.